# Determine if there is an active Microsoft Teams call via the Windows API

Tags: winapi

Is there a function in the Windows API that can be called to determine if there is an active Microsoft Teams call in progress?

Comment: No. Why would there be? MS Teams is just an application that runs on Windows, just like any other application that does so. The WinAPI has no special knowledge or functionality related to Teams, any more than it does of any other Windows program. Teams might have functionality in its API that could give you that information, but that would be part of Teams, not Windows or the WinAPI.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks, I imagined there would be some kind of API call that MS Teams makes to the OS to indicate that it is handling an active call so other applications (mine) can see if it should let an incoming call through or send the busy signal. I'd prefer not to query each application individually to check if it's currently handling a call as that would require enumerating them (I don't know which applications the client is running) and implementing this check for each application.

Comment: As I mentioned, as far as Windows is concerned, Teams is  just another app. What you're asking would require special knowledge of Teams by Windows, which does not exist.

Comment: Windows doesn't know about, or care about, any voice/video calls being made by any particular application.  You are going to have to hook into each individual application as needed.  Popular apps like Teams, Skype, etc are likely to expose their own APIs for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I believe my question is answered then. Shall I delete this question? Or leave it year in case someone else might find it useful?

Comment: Correction: *here

Comment: Actually, Windows should probably have an API (similiar to a mutex)  that programs such as these can call to say in session / out of session.  That way other programs could check this API and be friendly with resources while in session.  It's not an uncommon scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Microsoft Teams is a 3rd party application, just like [contoso.exe](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061013-05/?p=29393). There's nothing built into the system that would allow a client (or the OS, really) to query, whether a Teams (or Contoso) call is currently active.

If you are interested in Microsoft Teams specifically, it offers an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-concept-overview) for clients to interact with it. I don't know whether this includes services to query for the current state.

If, on the other hand, you are interested in finding out, whether any given camera or microphone is currently in exclusive use, you can ask the system to open the device for exclusive access, and draw conclusions from the results.